# RSS and rails 2.3.5 problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss

following to [Generating RSS feeds](http://railscasts.com/episodes/87-generating-rss-feeds) tutorial, i've created my RSS feed

It does't works.

Server throws following error:

> 406 Not Acceptable [http://localhost/articles.rss]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I need to explicitly declare response forma